# send SHIFT+H keystroke to screen

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-screen

I have a running process that I've started with screen.
I want to enable log file "on the fly" sending CTRL+a SHIFT+H from a script:

```
screen -dr process -X stuff ^A H , screen says --> -X: stuff: invalid option
screen -dr miner -X stuff "^A H" , screen says nothing but log file is not enabled
```

Using -p 0 does not make any difference.
Basically what I need is to send SHIFT+H as it seems that for screen it's not the same to send "H" than SHIFT+H

Answer (score 0):

Don't send the key strokes; just send the command `log` which is what `^A H` (by default) is bound to.

```
screen -dr process -X log
```

Comment: Great, it's just what I need it. System does not let me give you a point :-(

Comment: You should be able to accept the answer; I think you need a little more reputation before you are allowed to start upvoting answers.